# What does someone not good at "faking cheer” mean?

Tags: meaning

There was the following passage in New Yorker's (March 25) article titled "A bad day in American-Israeli relations:

> “I talk to him all the time. He is representing his country’s
>   interests the way he thinks he needs to, and I’m doing the same. This
>   can’t be reduced to a matter of, somehow, let’s all hold hands and
>   sing ‘Kumbaya.’ ” Obama has made this case before, in other
>   contexts—for example, in response to complaints that, if he only drank
>   more with Boehner, the Republicans would never shut down the
>   government. He is **not good at faking cheer**, and, in this case,
>   Netanyahu is not good at nurturing it in him.”

I think I can guess what “faking cheer” means by the context of the above sentence, but am not sure. Does it mean President isn’t very sociable? What is the exact translation of someone who is not good at faking cheer?

Google Ngram indicates that the words,"fake cheer" came into use in / around 1980 and is fast growing in its usage. Does it pass as a common turn of phrase today?

Comment: It means either that he is not good at pretending to be happy, or he's not good at "[making merry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/make+merry)", just to fit in socially. It's not so much that he isn't sociable, it's more that he's bad at pretending to have a good time.

Comment: Incidentally, the New Yorker is considered an extremely pretentious publication in the U.S., largely because it uses antiquated or inventive phrasing, as well as non-standard spellings (i.e. they actually spelled "cooperative" with an umlaut over one of the 'o's. Which is a bit insane considering ö isn't even a letter in the English alphabet). I would not recommend non-native speakers read the New Yorker. In fact, I'd go one further- I don't recommend anyone read the New Yorker.

Comment: ＠Parthian Shot. I used to ask questions about the expressions used in New York Times' columnist,Maureen Dowd’s articled, and have received comments from several users recommending me to read New Yorker instead of reading Dowd’s and other NYT writers’ articles. They told in their comment that the New Yorker’s articles are contemporary and refined in its style. You say New Yorker’s writings stink. As a non-native English speaker, I can not judge which side is true.

Comment: Readers who cannot tell the difference between an umlaut and a diaeresis are well advised to follow Parthian Shot's recommendation never to read the *New Yorker*. Otherwise their heads might explode, what with all the pretentious non-standard inventiveness and suchlike that they're liable to run into there. And who would want *that?*

Comment: That's fair- I should be clearer. I think the quality of the journalism is good, and if you understand most of it, and enjoy it, then of course you should read it. However, I have noticed odd turns of phrase do show up in the articles occasionally, so if you see an unfamiliar spelling or phrase, a good default assumption is that it's uncommon overall. That's partly an artifact of the [reading level](http://gawker.com/5714007/how-dumb-is-your-favorite-website), and partly because it has a more literary target audience (so they feel more comfortable playing with language).

Comment: @ErikKowal If someone's learning English for the first time, then no, they would not want to learn that using a diaeresis is any kind of normal. Largely because English doesn't have obligate diacritical marks, and adding them almost never serves any purpose other than to stroke the author's ego.

Comment: Thank you. It is always a pleasure to debate with a subject expert.

Comment: I really dig the New Yorker's journalism and cartoons, not so much their poetry selections.

Comment: I must warn the OP that some of the cartoons in the New Yorker are un-funny, even to native AmE speakers. Maybe New Yorkers "get" all of them—not I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other commentators have suggested **faking cheer** just means pretending to be cheerful. Cheer can mean a general demeanour as well as a literal cheer, (a cheerful person) and **faking** means having the outward appearance of something which does not reflect reality.

It does not necessarily mean that someone is not sociable. Among people they actually want to socialise with, -- people they see eye-to-eye with and consider freidns -- they may be the life and soul of the party. In those situations, he would be *genuinely* cheerful.

However, there may be times when it would benefit someone to pretend that they were having a great time with someone they dislike. People vary in their ability to "pretend", or fake, enjoyment with those they dislike or who they know dislike them. Too little of such an ability to **fake cheer** suggests social ineptness, too much suggests underlying dishonesty.